# Is it possible to store video and audio in django database?

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, web

I am trying to create a diary entry application using django which has video and audio input options. What i want is:
1)Create start recording button in my template which seek camera and audio permissions and start recording
2)Create a stop recording button which will send the recording to my views.py function and that function will store the video/audio as an object of class created in models.py
Are these two steps possible to achieve with html and javascript as frontend and django in backend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

short answer: yes

long answer, I would not store large binary data in the database, rather than using a file object type in the database to point to a file, usually uploaded to the "media" directory of your project.

refer to [Managing files in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/files/)

Comment: you're welcome. If this answer helped you, please accept it